# Ubuntu 12.04 CD-R doesn't start when i start the PC

Tags: 12.04, installation, live-cd, windows-8, samsung

I've got an Ubuntu CD-R and a Samsung Laptop with Windows 8 64 Bit.
When i start the Laptop with the Ubuntu CD-R in it, it shows the Samsung-sign, makes a "Beep" tune, shows the normal "Loading-Circle" and then Windows 8 starts normaly... 
I know something about changing the boot device in the Bios, but my laptop doesn't show the normal message "Press F12 to Bios setup", its just the Samsung-sign and then Windows 8 boots, so i dont know how to enter the bios...
Tank you for your help and sorry for my bad English :)

Answer (score 0):

Without a specific model, it's hard to tell you exactly how to do this, but:

SafeBoot is likely to be blocking CD boot, so you are indeed headed in the right direction.
Note that not all BIOSes want F12 - some like DEL, some F2 and so on.

Also, ensure you are in fact pressing the F key - on my HP Pavilion G6, to get F2 I have to hold [fn] + [BRIGHTNESS DOWN], to get F3 I have to hold [fn] + [BRIGHTNESS UP] and so on.